# Why do 5 drives disappear when I scan for them?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, sata

I am trying to diagnose why my raid6 array of 20 hard drives stopped working on my ubuntu installation. I noticed that when I tried to force it to start, several drives simply stopped being listed in the raid, and as drives at all on my computer.

I thought it was a hardware problem and opened up my case to fiddle with the SATA wires. I stopped the raid and then unplugged and replugged some wires and wanted to force the computer to check for new sata devices. I searched and found an answer on this website that told me to execute this command to refresh sata devices:

```
for host in /sys/class/scsi_host/*; do echo "- - -" | sudo tee $host/scan; ls /dev/sd* ; done
```

The output of the command showed drives disappearing. (for interpretation, drives sdb-sdu are part of the raid6 array, and the command made 4 of them -- sdo, sdp, sdq, and sdr -- disappear)

```
 - - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sdo  /dev/sdq  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdp  /dev/sdr  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sdo  /dev/sdq  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdp  /dev/sdr  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sdp  /dev/sdr  /dev/sdt
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdq  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
- - -
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk  /dev/sdm  /dev/sds  /dev/sdu
/dev/sda1  /dev/sdb   /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj  /dev/sdl  /dev/sdn  /dev/sdt
```

I physically checked the connections of the drives that disappeared by unplugging SATA wires and seeing if more drives disappeared. By that process of elimination I was able to find out that the 4 drives that disappeared are all connected to the 8 port PCIE-to-SATA card that I have been using without issue for at least 4 years now.

I rebooted my system several times and also noticed that several hard drives were missing on boot, but then appeared, with accompanying beeps, after I opened up the Ubuntu Disks utility. And then when I issued the command above again, 4 drives again disappeared.

The raid6 array is currently in disarray, with some drives reporting different values for how many drives are connected and when the last change was. I have tried to --force it to assemble twice already and it worked, and started on a rebuild, but then 2 or more drives would disappear from the operating system entirely and the rebuild would freeze.

Is it the card? Should I replace it?

edit: This is the card in question: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Marvell-Chipset-8-Ports-SATA-3-0-6GB-PCI-Express-Card-NCQ-Port-Multiplier-FIS/191962272465?hash=item2cb1d7d2d1:g:-UMAAOxy4t1SmhAS

And here is what it says in dmesg from when I stopped the raid array and then issued the next command to check sata devices:

```
[   65.849212] md: md0 stopped.
[   76.462011] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   76.463189] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   76.791618] ahci 0000:06:00.0: FBS is disabled
[   76.951538] ahci 0000:06:00.0: FBS is enabled
[   76.952111] ata10.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 330)
[   77.267083] ata10.01: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   77.581891] ata10.02: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   77.894936] ata10.03: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   78.211968] ata10.04: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   78.215129] ata10.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   82.816960] ata10.01: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   83.128896] ata10.02: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   83.440843] ata10.03: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   83.752802] ata10.04: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   88.192093] ata10.01: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   88.504051] ata10.02: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   88.815986] ata10.03: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   89.127946] ata10.04: SATA link down (SStatus 610 SControl 330)
[   89.127970] ata10.01: disabled
[   89.127988] ata10.02: disabled
[   89.128003] ata10.03: disabled
[   89.128018] ata10.04: disabled
[   89.128332] ata10.01: detaching (SCSI 10:1:0:0)
[   89.129036] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdo] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   89.129059] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdo] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.129060] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdo] Stopping disk
[   89.129066] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdo] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.185725] ata10.02: detaching (SCSI 10:2:0:0)
[   89.186427] sd 10:2:0:0: [sdp] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   89.186454] sd 10:2:0:0: [sdp] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.186455] sd 10:2:0:0: [sdp] Stopping disk
[   89.186461] sd 10:2:0:0: [sdp] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.253718] ata10.03: detaching (SCSI 10:3:0:0)
[   89.254504] sd 10:3:0:0: [sdq] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   89.254528] sd 10:3:0:0: [sdq] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.254529] sd 10:3:0:0: [sdq] Stopping disk
[   89.254535] sd 10:3:0:0: [sdq] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.317679] ata10.04: detaching (SCSI 10:4:0:0)
[   89.318503] sd 10:4:0:0: [sdr] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   89.318527] sd 10:4:0:0: [sdr] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.318528] sd 10:4:0:0: [sdr] Stopping disk
[   89.318534] sd 10:4:0:0: [sdr] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   89.460199] ata11: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   89.462818] ata11.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   89.796131] ata12: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   89.798858] ata12.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   90.132065] ata13: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   90.133201] ata13.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[   90.134221] ata13.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[   90.134227] ata13.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   90.472068] ata14: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   90.808247] ata15: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   91.147895] ata16: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   91.484079] ata17: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   91.824122] ata18: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[   91.824750] ata18.00: configured for UDMA/66
[   92.155995] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   92.157411] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   92.491879] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   92.494534] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   92.827218] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   92.828045] ata4.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[   92.830499] ata4.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[   92.832149] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   93.847192] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   93.849644] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   94.175633] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   94.177221] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   94.664704] ata7: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   94.667911] ata7.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   95.152651] ata8: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   96.732470] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   97.236448] ata9: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   97.237568] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

Comment: what do those (dis)appearances look like in dmesg?

Comment: OK I added the dmesg output to the question.